# Compiling a Node.js (github action) into a single file using `@zeit/ncc`

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare, github-actions, zeit-ncc

I'am trying to compile a Node.js package (github action) into single file using `@zeit/ncc` NPM package, but some dependencies don't get copied to dist directory.

For example my package depends on `7z-min` and `nightmare` NPM packages. Running `ncc build index.js` build single file successfully and copies `7z` binaries for each platform correctly but `nightmare` electron binaries don't get copied. Only a file called `path.txt` containing `dist/electron.exe`.

When running my github action it fail to find electron executable.

Comment: Was this ever fixed? Can you share the github action for this.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you might have not imported the package in the JS file.